# Parsing XML in SQL, atypical attribute format

Tags: xml, sql-server-2012

This XML format is a given (it comes from an app my company runs):

```
<User display="User">NAME1</User>
```

So I've been running the following code to try and tease out the true value (NAME1) from this format:

```
declare @xml xml = '<User display="User">NAME1</User>'
select @xml.value('(User/@display)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as USER_NM
```

I'm using SQL Server 2012. But nothing I try can pick out the `NAME1`, rather than `User`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just use this snippet instead:

```
SELECT @xml.value('(User)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as USER_NM
```

This will read out the textual value of the `<User>` element - `NAME1` in your case